# Java Unit Testing Completeness Indicator Tool?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am talking about the real 'Test Completeness', not the traditional 'Code Coverage'，because Code Coverage is not very helpful when people start asking for more accurate estimations.

And by 'Test Completeness' I mean that (virtually) ALL possible usages of a function are covered, including Border conditions of the arguments, etc.

There is another Stackoverflow thread discussing this topic, but no java tool is mentioned in it. [Is there a good measure of completeness of Unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041885/is-there-a-good-measure-of-completeness-of-unit-tests)

Is there such as tool that can take a look at the current JUnit Tests and tell me approximately the percentage of completeness?

Thanks.

Comment: If only you had been using .NET, you could be using the tool Pex to do exactly this. It's such an amazing tool. I haven't found the Java-equivalent yet (I haven't looked either), but I would really want one, too. I may be bored enough one day to make my own "Pex ripoff".

Comment: Post a link to the definition of Test Completeness.

Comment: [Asking for tools is off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for [so]. And questions about testing may fit better on [sqa.se] (no idea what their policy is on asking for tools, my guess is that it's similar).

Comment: @Dukeling: "[...] but if your question generally covers… [...] software tools commonly used by programmers [...] … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" It's pretty much on topic then, isn't it?

Comment: @Izmaki With regard to asking for tools, that's **explicitly** forbidden - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, ... are off-topic". What you quoted would typically cover questions about specific IDE functionality and such. With regard to possibly belonging on the testing site, the [so] on-topic page is way too broad, the basic guideline is: if it's on-topic somewhere else, ask it there instead.

Comment: Sorry that it's off-topic. I have asked the question in http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ already. Please delete this thread here.

Answer (score 2):

Have a search for Mutation Testing.  An example is http://pitest.org/.  Basically it changes your code and reruns the tests (like x == true changes to x == false), if your tests don't fail when the change is made then your tests are insufficient.

Comment: while I'm a big fan of mutation testing (I've even written my own) that doesn't cover "completeness" the way the OP stated.  Mutation testing is a great way to make sure not only are tests covering the code but actually assert correctly.  There isn't anything a mutation tester can do to make sure you have covered all boundary conditions you still have to write more tests for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a "white-box" tester.  There is a commercial program called [JTest](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/jtest.jsp?itemId=14) but I've never used it myself.